# Default sample value for viewport and render

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

since the latest versions I have one problem. Every time when I create a new project I have to reduce viewport and render "max samples" value, because they are too high for what I am doing, and especially my test renders (1024 for viewport and 4096 for render).
So, the question is, **is there any way to change the default sample value to my own**, so I won't have to reduce it every time

Comment: Sure. Open Blender with its default scene. Change the samples value. Go to _File_ > _Defaults_ > _Save Startup File_ and confirm the question "OK? Save Startup File" by clicking on it.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much